# Permision denied when using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I get the following error when I try to run a pyspark program:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.0/bin/load-spark-env.sh: line 2:   
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.0/libexec/bin/load-spark-env.sh: Permission denied
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.0/bin/load-spark-env.sh: line 2: 
exec: /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.0/libexec/bin/load-spark-env.sh: cannot execute: Undefined error: 0
```

I have tried:

```
unset SPARK_HOME && spark-submit
```

but then I get a different error:

```
KeyError: 'SPARK_HOME
```

Any idea how to fix this?
I am running python 2.7 on OSX 10.11

Answer (score 4):

Check the permissions on:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.0.2/libexec/bin/load-spark-env.sh
```

I had a similar issue and that file was marked as 'read only' for me (my user id) and execution rights only to root.

Note that when you invoke pyspark it redirects to the above shell script. So you can trigger the process but as the actual shell script does not have 'x' permissions for you - it fails.

Alternatively, `sudo -H pyspark` would also do the trick.

Happy Sparking!

Answer (score 2):

```
export SPARK_HOME=/path/to/spark/installation
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/build:$PYTHONPATH
```

Executing above on your terminal allows you to add SPARK_HOME as an environment variable, which is later appended to your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: These two lines are already in my profile. I put them there after installation


SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.0
PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:$SPARK_HOME/libexec/python:$SPARK_HOME/libexec/python$